# Using Cocos2D scheduleUpdate to delay loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have an algorithm that takes a few seconds to load some stuff, and I want to first set the string on a label to say "loading" before the actual loading begins. This is all within the same layer, this is not switching between scenes.

I thought I could simply do this:

```
-(void)startLoading{

[self unscheduleAllSelectors];//just in case the update is already scheduled

[self.loadingLabel setString:@"Loading...."];

[self scheduleUpdate];

 }
```

Then, I have this:

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta{
[self unscheduleUpdate];
[self beginLoading];//another method that loads all the stuff

 }
```

My understanding is that my method `beginLoading` should not run until the next frame. Thus my label should get updated correctly.  However this is not happening. There is a slight freeze while all my assets get loaded and my label never gets updated before the loading begins.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Are you calling startLoading from an init function in a scene/layer? This thread appears to have a solution... http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15998

Comment: that thread is referring to a different issue. my update is running, but it is not waiting one frame, or if it is, the prior frame is not completing before the new frame starts, which i didn't think was possible. i am not calling from an init method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope ure not missing anything. I stopped fighting this and now use this kind of 'delayed' task catapult. It should make certain you will get a draw in the transition from the first to the second tick:

```
-(void) startLoading{
    _loadTicker=0; // an NSUInteger iVar declared in the .h
    [self schedule:@selector(tickOffLoading:)];
}

-(void) tickOffLoading:(ccTime) dt{

    _loadTicker++;
    if(_loadTicker==1) {
        [self.loadingLabel setString:@"Loading...."];
    } else {
        [self unschedule:@selector(tickOffLoading:)];
        [self beginLoading];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, you and i had a similar idea. i ended up still using the regular `update` method, but am also using a frame counter ivar

Comment: @andrewx : lol, not really surprised, similar problems will engender similar solutions. This sets the stage nicely for loading in a background task , since you can cascade the ticker check to 1,2,3, etc ...

Comment: i still wonder why it doesn't work as expected initially. i guess update must run on the same "frame" or run loop when it is initially scheduled.